# After I upgraded to DDR4-3200 32 GB on a MAG X570 MSI, I'm getting a double beep... but everything works fine

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard, speed, ddr

This is a strange situation for me.

I'm building a machine for my wife, and since it uses a compatible motherboard (identical except MPG instead of MAG), I'm also passing my old DDR4-2400 to her and upgrading to DDR-3200. It should work with this motherboard and for everything up to and including gaming, and it appears to (I'm posting with it right now); however, when in BIOS after installing it, I continually hear a double-beep from inside the case.

I believe this means there's a parity error for MSI, but that doesn't make sense to me. When I first inserted the RAM, I did not get this beep but did adjust the type of RAM to DDR4-3200 in advanced settings.

To be very specific, I ordered [this](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08NVQZ9XQ?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1). I have no interest in overclocking, and I'm hoping that's not what this is telling me, as I'm aiming for the defaults. I tried resetting the CMOS settings to their default with F6, but I'm still getting the double beep.

It is again on a MAG x570 Tomahawk Wifi motherboard. Temperatures are around 50 C idle, it ran a particularly finicky game without issue. But, I'm getting the dreaded double-beep.

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

For the record, I generally boot Linux Mint on this machine, and while I have plenty of system tools, they won't be the same as on Windows. I believe this is a BIOS setting issue anyway.

All of the bug LEDs on the motherboard are off during normal operation, including the DDR4 one; `hardinfo` does detect 32 GB. Interestingly, `dmidecode --type 17` gives me a RAM speed of 2400 MHz. Does it automatically throttle the RAM speed?

Comment: "Does it automatically throttle the RAM speed?" - Yes

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, good to know! I'm starting to suspect that this is RAM that requires A-XMP to run at its labeled 3200 MT/s, I just want to make sure I'm not risking bricking something important. If that turns out to be it, I'll update this question; but it might be a day or two before I touch anything again.

Comment: (I've bumped into several other complaints from people who had some other DDR4-3200 run at 2400 MHz, and A-XMP ended up being the solution. It would make sense if attempting to run this RAM at JEDEC 3200, even though that's supported on other devices, was resulting in a memory parity error and it got throttled back down to 2400 MHz for system stability.)

Comment: How are you going to brick something by installing memory that is compatible with your motherboard?

Comment: It's been a while since I fiddled with hardware on this level-- maybe 2018-- so I'm consulting with Super User before I do anything rash; that's all. I'm not familiar with a lot of these new terms, and am basically learning again. Also, lord only knows where I put my CMOS jumper if it comes down to it. 